# str to int Python 3

Tags: python, string, list, int

i'm trying to make int all the elements in a list that is filled with inputs. I tried this options and nither of them are working.

```
initial_price=int(input("Price: "))
purchase_amounts=[initial_price]
while purchase_amounts:
    amount=input("Price: ")
    if amount.lower()=="done":
        break
    else:
        purchase_amounts+=amount

for x in purchase_amounts:
    int(x)

print(purchase_amounts)
```

The return is this one (Just the first item is int):

```
Price: 34
Price: 54
Price: 34
Price: done
[34, '5', '4', '3', '4']
```

I also tried this:

```
initial_price=int(input("Price: "))
purchase_amounts=[initial_price]
while purchase_amounts:
    amount=input("Price: ")
    if amount.lower()=="done":
        break
    else:
        purchase_amounts+=int(amount)

print(purchase_amounts)
```

But it returns this error:

```
Price: 34
Price: 65
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f2b484e3ce61> in <module>()
      8         break
      9     else:
---> 10         purchase_amounts+=int(amount)
     11 
     12 print(purchase_amounts)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What error ? Can you show us the stack trace ?

Comment: I just updated it

Comment: `purchase_amounts` is of type `list` so this operation is not valid `purchase_amounts+=int(amount)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in this line:

```
purchase_amounts += int(amount)
```

This is how you should append elements to a list:

```
purchase_amounts.append(int(amount))
```

Now your list is made up of ints from the beginning! For completeness sake, this is how you can convert an existing list of strings into ints:

```
[int(x) for x in purchase_amounts]
```

Or alternatively:

```
list(map(int, purchase_amounts))
```

Answer (score 3):

How about that ?

```
def inputs():
    while True:
        s = input('enter: ')
        if not s:
            break
        yield s

print([int(i) for i in inputs()])
```

Why the error in your code you might ask, because you do this:

```
purchase_amounts+=amount
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
purchase_amounts = [] + 1  # cannot add a list and an int
```